# How can I connect an unthreaded boom spigot to a 3/8"connector?

Tags: accessories

How can I connect an unthreaded boom spigot to a 3/8"connector?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an adapter like this:

[image: Manfrotto 014-38 Rapid Adapter - 5/8" Stud to 3/8" Thread]

That's the [Manfrotto 014-38 Rapid Adapter - 5/8" Stud to 3/8" Thread](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/546490-REG/Manfrotto_014_38_014_38_Rapid_Adapter.html)

Note that you can attach the 5/8" pin in either horizontal configuration (through the holes) or vertically (from the bottom).

Specific example for illustrative purpose — you can find these in other brands in various qualities and prices.

Comment: Super. 90° options. I saw that before at $23 and said absolutely not.
BH - $13; Amazon - $10. And for fun I will leave a review that says "Doesn't work on a Kindle."

Comment: $20+ does seem pretty rich. On the other hand, if you're attaching hundreds of dollars of equipment, or if failure at the wrong time could otherwise be costly — well, I'd at least avoid the super-cheap no-name ones.

Comment: Perfect. 90° as well. BH new - $13; Amazon $10; BH used $8! ... but you can't order until Tuesday night. Amazon done. Thank you.

Comment: You can get lots of variations on a theme, including ones with a removable 'hat' that supports both thread sizes too & becomes the stud end if required, 2 or 3 quid/bucks/shekels on eBay. BTW, did you try unscrewing that stud end/'hat'?